# Magic trackpad clicks all time

Tags: trackpad, magic-trackpad

As I move the cursor with my finger on the surface of the trackpad it just clicks all the time.

It seems like the trackpad went mad. I mean that it just selects everything click everywhere where the cursor is. It is unusable. It started just 2 days ago.

Any advise what can I do?

Comment: Did something happen 2 days ago or earlier? - For example has the computer been subjected to liquids, shocks or anything like that?

Comment: Check whether the battery is swollen

Comment: No battery swollen, no liquid, no shocks... It happened a year ago as well then it dissapeard... Not sure if this is related to the latest macOs update or not but it just happens...